# c# cmd.ExecuteReader() Hang up

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and want to call store procedure in the sql server database ,for that purpose write this code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ipaddress;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=userid;Password=password;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec web.sp_getTotalBillPayam "+Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumber) +",'"+password.Trim()+"',72107603,1067", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ...
```

when run that code every thing is ok but store procedure not return to me any result ,goto debug i realized in this line run:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

but debugger not go to the next line of code and wait that line run finish,after 5 min that line not finish and dont go next line of code,what happen?How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: if its a stored proc, execute it as commandtype storeprocedure

Comment: Did run the stored proc directly on the db from sql management studio with the same parameters?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes my friend run direct that sp and after 5 minute return result

Comment: @brykneval that is sp on sql server my freind

Comment: Without the Store Procedure code, it will be hard to give correct code; what are the input parameters? the output or return parameters? or is it a SELECT?

Comment: @MadMyche my input is clear in on my code,but output is select query result

Comment: @stackstack Without the SP code the input is not clear. Need the parameter names to properly set them up and to not risk SQL injection via the concatenated command you have.

Comment: C# code and sql server are running on the same computer,? If they are on different computers then you won't get the same performance as the same computer. Apart from sp execution time there will be network latency. Did you wait little longer than 5 mins? After how many minutes you are getting result in the code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes run at the same computer

Comment: Can you please include the definition of `sp_getTotalBillPayam` , as well as the code that uses `reader`?

Answer (score 1):

Your command is not attached to your connection-- and your use of parameters is dangerous.  Try this instead:

**EDIT: Sorry, your command is attached to the connection, didn't see that being passed in.  Either way, this is the correct pattern for calling a stored proc**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ipaddress;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=userid;Password=password;")) {
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "web.sp_getTotalBillPayam";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //repeat this for each parameter
        var parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "PhoneNumber";    //this must match whatever your parameters are to your stored proc
        parameter.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int64;
        parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = phoneNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        ...
        //if you have an OUTPUT result from your proc, add a a parameter called RETURNS with a direction of ParameterDirection.Return and check value AFTER executing

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            //if your results are a SELECT query they will be here
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please wait to test that my friend

Comment: my friend not work your code,dont go to next line after this line: using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

Comment: Of course it doesn't work as rolled here, Tim does not have all the needed information from your Procedure. But it is a start for you to work off of